# Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-3.0

My Android Studio setup is as follows :

```
Android Studio Version : 4.0 (May 2020 Build)
Android Gradle Plugin Version : 4.0.0
Gradle Version : 6.1.1
```

But it gives me this error :

```
Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.1
```

I checked in the SDK tools in the sdk manager and there is no 30.0.1 version persent but 30.0.2 version is present.
To force Android Studio to use 30.0.2 i added the below line in the app's gradle properties in the android tag

android {
..
..
..

buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

}

But stuill it is showing the same error.
I think every Gradle+plugin version is mapped to a given **Buildtoolversion** and for my one it is **30.0.1** but sadly SDK tool version doesnt show it.
Is there a way to know which **gradle+plugin** version corresponds to 30.0.2?

Rp

Comment: Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)

Answer (score 42):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by doing this:

1. Go to `File->Project Structure`
2. Click to the `Modules` in the right column
3. In `Properties` tab, select a `Build Tools Version` in the dropdown list.
4. Click `Apply` then `OK`

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Failed to notify build listener.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  Could not create task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
  Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.
> Failed to stop service 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueReporterImpl$GlobalSyncIssueService_8e6cc65d-b5a3-43f1-bd47-f29bfbbd8a77'.
   > Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.2

Answer (score 33):

I have the same problem as you, but my android studio prompt:

```
Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3
```

I click the menu `Tools - SDK Manager` to check why there isn't 30.0,3;

I found that, in the `SDK platforms` tab list, there is showing

```
Name                  API Level     Revision    Status
Android 11.0(R)       30            3           Update available
```

I opened directory to dig:

```
dir %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\build-tools
```

there are these things, no 30.0.3 is there;

```
2021/11/02  20:02    <DIR>          .
2021/11/03  08:37    <DIR>          ..
2020/12/25  12:46    <DIR>          30.0.2
2021/10/27  15:16    <DIR>          31.0.0
2021/03/17  17:07    <DIR>          31.0.0-rc1
2021/05/07  14:57    <DIR>          31.0.0-rc3
2021/11/02  20:02    <DIR>          32.0.0-rc1
```

So, conclusion is that specified version of buildTool is missing cause the problem, we should Install the missing version;

However, I can't upgrade 30.0.2 to 30.0.3 because there is no dash, and only checkmark in checkbox , I can't check the checkbox to upgrade it  , so I have to install them both;

You can following the steps in the picture to install the missing version;

`Tools - SDK Manager - SDK Tools - Show Package Details`

Select the version you need, and click apply button to install it;

[image]

Comment: This helped resolved the issue for me.

Comment: My problem is `flutter Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3` and installed 30.0.3 in android sdk build tools. after that resolved for me.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the step:-
Open Android studio then
Tools->SDK Manager ->SDK Tools

see below right show package check then you will see the SDK Tools version and you can download it by check and apply  then ok.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by doing this:

1. Go to Settings.
2. Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK
3. install android 12 in SDK Platform

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIhlg.png)

Comment: The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-25).
Dependency: androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0.
AAR metadata

Answer (score 1):

I think I may be able to help.

Not sure how it started happening as I was already running a simple app project without any problem. But then, after installing an "amazon package", I started having the same issue every time I created a new project.

The solution I have found is in two steps has i have found 2 different errors in sequence.

Btw the issue started happening even with no changes to the default My Application

Started from here:
[image: New Application]

First Error:

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
> [image]

To Solve this go to (on Mac not sure on win) preferences->Build,Execution...->Build Tools->Gradle

here I had a version of java that I have no clue out end out there. You have to change to vers 11 and apply

[image]

After this however you may still face another issue try to run the app

Second Error:
Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.2
Install Build Tools 30.0.2 and sync project

[image]

to fix this you go to File Project Structure

and select the same API for the Compile and Build

[image]

Once you are done with it the project should start working again

I have no idea whats the route cause thou... and everytime i create a new project gotta do the same...

Answer (score 0):

Error it self saying. In your system build-tool version not found.

In MacOS Go to the

```
 Library -> Android -> sdk -> build-tool
```

And see here which version are available

For download desire version go to the

```
AndroidStudio -> SDKManager -> SDKtools
```

And download the missing one and try to build again.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the required Android SDK.
File > Settings > System Settings > Android SDK
then select the android SDK according to the android device you are using.
then download and install it.
This problem will go after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

That should work please
Ask manager,move on to ask tools and tuck the show package details box you should see that the build tools version is not installed and install it
Ccongs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

go to  `file -> project structure -> modules` and set `Build Tools Version` to the most recent in the list, hit OK on the bottom of dialog and run your app.