# Android studio emulator not working despite it shows on taskbar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I start my android studio and press run app button, the Emulator starts but it doesn't display any thing. On the taskbar, the emulator icon is displayed but the emulator is not opening.

Comment: Assuming the app has built correctly, are there any error messages in the 'Run' window?

Comment: it is showing Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you looked here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63718190/failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-30-0-1)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, it was showing an error because of the resolution. So I make the resolution lower and the emulator was running quite fine. If you face the same problem please try to lower the resolution of your device