# problem in android studio "Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.2"

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed android studio and now when I try to run the first application an error occurred:

```
"Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.2"
```

What should I do ?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's a VERY common problem.  There's a bug in Android Studio--you can't build with that version.  Try a different version of your app's sdk in the `targetSdk` line of your app/build.gradle file (confusingly there are more than one build.gradle files!).  But this is really a hack.  The real solution is to update your tools as per the link below--you'd think that Google would test each version of Android Studio to make sure it works, but you'd think wrong.  Ha!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63718190/failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-30-0-1)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem like below:

```
Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3
```

**My Environment**

I am using *Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS* and my SDK location is in a different directory.

**Root Cause**

The wrong *sdk.dir* is defined in *local.properties* by default.

[image]

Also SDK path is not set into *Project Settings*(File>Project Structure)

[image: No SDK Path is set.]

**Solution**

Go to *Project Settings*(File>Project Structure) and add your SDK path like below.

[image: Proper SDK Path in project settings]

After adding the SDK path, you will find the proper *sdk.dir* is defined in *local.properties* like below:

[image: Right SDK Path in local properties]

Comment: If you are not able to find any build tools then you need to go to SDK manager.
SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Download the missing one.