# There is a problem when run ''flutter build apk''

Tags: flutter, apk

when run "flutter build apk" returns

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalReportRelease'.
> Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           24.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

and in build.gradle file there is this problem:

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip'.
Could not dispatch a message to the daemon.
Could not write '/127.0.0.1:60091'.
Connection reset by peer
```

flutter doctor is all good,
java version is "java 18.0.2.1"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63718190/failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-30-0-1)

Comment: Try running  `flutter doctor` on cmd.

Comment: Flutter Doctor will only detect problems related to flutter setup and the presence of needed JDKs. OP is probably having a problem with Build Tools dependencies, as the linked question above states. 

Such issue won't be detected by flutter doctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue you are facing is related to Flutter not being able to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3. You can try resolving this by ensuring that the specified Build Tools version is installed in your Android SDK. You can open the Android SDK Manager and check if version 30.0.3 of Build Tools is installed. If not, you can install it from there. Additionally, you can try running the command with the --stacktrace option to get more detailed information on the error.
[image]

Comment: thank you...I also download Sdkplatform 30 so it works.